# Use regular expression to extract elements from a pandas data frame

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, series

From the following data frame:

```
d = {'col1':['a-1524112-124', 'b-1515', 'c-584854', 'a-15154']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

My ultimate goal is to extract the letters a, b or c (as string) in a pandas series. For that I am using the `.findall()` method from the `re` module, as shown below:

```
# import the module
import re
# define the patterns
pat = 'a|b|c'

# extract the patterns from the elements in the specified column
df['col1'].str.findall(pat)
```

The problem is that the output i.e. the letters a, b or c, in each row, will be present in a **list** (of a single element), as shown below:

```
Out[301]: 
0    [a]
1    [b]
2    [c]
3    [a]
```

While I would like to have the letters a, b or c as string, as shown below:

```
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
```

I know that if I combine `re.search()` with `.group()` I can get a string, but if I do:

```
df['col1'].str.search(pat).group()
```

I will get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'search'
```

Using `.str.split()` won't do the job because, in my original dataframe, I want to capture strings that might contain the delimiter (e.g. I might want to capture `a-b`)

Does anyone know a simple solution for that, perhaps avoiding iterative operations such as a for loop or list comprehension?

Comment: have you tried this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your code

```
pat = 'a|b|c'
df['col1'].str.findall(pat).str[0]
Out[309]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) with capturing groups:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1':['a-1524112-124', 'b-1515', 'c-584854', 'a-15154']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

result = df['col1'].str.extract('(a|b|c)')

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  a
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try with [str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) like this- `df["col1"].str.split("-", n = 1, expand = True)`

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1':['a-1524112-124', 'b-1515', 'c-584854', 'a-15154']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df['col1'] = df["col1"].str.split("-", n = 1, expand = True) 
print(df.head())
```

**Output:**

```
  col1
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
```

Comment: In fact this does the job for this sample example, though, in my original df, splitting the observations won't do the job because what I want to capture might contain the `-` symbol. i.e. I also want to capture something like `a-b`

Comment: @BCArg then edit your question and let us know more about what are the possible value of your col1?

Comment: @BCArg how does `df['col1'].str.findall(pat).str[0]` capture `a-b`?

Comment: it will in case I specify that I want to capture it. In my original data frame I have a handful of parameters which I want to capture, hence I don't need to be sophisticated with regular expressions.