# How to extract elements from a list in pandas through regex?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I'm looking to extract the string of numbers that come after 'accession' in this Dataframe. My dataframe looks like this:

```
targets_list = pd.DataFrame(targets_df[['target_components', 'target_chembl_id']])
```

and the elements in each column of the `target_components` looks like the following:

```
[{'accession': 'O43451', 'component_description': 'Maltase-glucoamylase, intestinal', 'component_id': 434, 'component_type': 'PROTEIN', 'relationship': 'SINGLE PROTEIN', 'target_component_synonyms',...}]
```

I would just like to extract the number code after 'accession'. As I thought it was the first element of the list, I tried to `tgt = targets_list['target_components'][0][0]`, but this returns the first element of that list, but not the accession number.

I can see that it is a list that's in each row, but how to parse that list and get that number and add it to a column is what's missing for me. It should be possible with Regex maybe? But I'm not sure how Regex works at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
tgt = targets_list["target_components"].str[0].str["accession"]
```

Result for

```
targets_list = pd.DataFrame(
    {"target_components": [
        [{"accession": "O43451", "b": "c", "d": 1}],
        [{"accession": "012345", "b": "e", "d": 2}],
        [{"b": "f", "d": 3}],
        []]}
)
```

```
                              target_components
0  [{'accession': 'O43451', 'b': 'c', 'd': 1}]
1  [{'accession': '012345', 'b': 'e', 'd': 2}]
2                         [{'b': 'f', 'd': 3}]
3                                           []
```

is

```
0    O43451
1    012345
2      None
3       NaN
Name: target_components, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! This does end up working. I was messing around with something similar, I was trying to do `targets_list["target_components"][0][0].get["accession"]`, which does work but then it copies only the first code and replicates it across the whole list. I couldn't figure out how to get pandas to do that with every row, but this works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .findall() function or .extract() to get the id.

Refer to :
[Use regular expression to extract elements from a pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077038/use-regular-expression-to-extract-elements-from-a-pandas-data-frame)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
targets_list['target_components'].map(lambda x: x[0].get("accession"] if x else '')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I was trying something similar with .get('accesssion'), but unfortunately both of these ways throws an error of "list index out of range", as well as the way that the above commenter answered! I'm not sure what this error even exactly means.

Comment: There might be an empty list. Try .map(lambda x: x[0]["accession"] if x else '')

Answer (score 0):

First there is no need to use `pd.DataFrame` again to create dataframe from existing columns:

```py
targets_list = targets_df[['target_components', 'target_chembl_id']]
```

Then you can use `apply` to access the column element

```py
tgt = targets_list['target_components'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['accession'])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I was trying something similar with `.get('accesssion')`, but unfortunately both of these ways throws an error of "list index out of range".

Comment: @Raighley Can you demonstrate that all values in column `target_components` is list with at least one item?

Comment: Hi, if you want me to demonstrate that with code, I'm not sure exactly how I can show that to you. But as for a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/XlRcyAk.png of how the dataset looks like. 

Additionally, this is what each individual element in the list looks like with `targets_list['target_components'][0][0]`: https://i.imgur.com/mpsrpr1.png

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Raighley It looks fine to me, could you post the screenshot of your error code? In `targets_list['target_components'][0][0]`, `targets_list['target_components']` is the Series; `targets_list['target_components'][0]` returns the first row; so `targets_list['target_components'][0][0]` returns the first list item of first row.

Comment: @Raighley Can you run `[lst[0] for lst in targets_list['target_components']]` this list comprehension and test if it could run without error?

Comment: The solution of the commenter above does end up working! I tried with `targets_list["target_components"][0][0].get("accession")`, but this only returned the first code of the first row and replicated it across all rows. Was trying to figure out how to do it for each row, but the solution above works well.